# How does this capacitor operate in this circuit?

Tags: arduino, transistors, capacitor

I have been studying a circuit developed by Amir.  He has made a mailbox notifier. It sends an email to your phone when the mailman puts mail in your mailbox.
What's supposed to happen can be explained by Amir's words below.

> Opening the reed switch will close the transistor and then open it after a short time. When the transistor is closed, the reset is HIGH (due to the internal PULL-UP resistor). When the transistor is open the reset is LOW because of the "short circuit" to GND through the transistor. By making sure the left two resistors have high values, almost no current flows through them. (I chose 100K, 10K).

Basically, he is trying to pull the Reset pin of the wifi module to Ground for a small amount of time.

Here is the website: http://www.whatimade.today/esp-8266-mailbox-notifier-using-deepsleep-and-blynk/
[image]

The schematic contains an esp8266-07 module, a reed switch, a 100k resistor, 10k resistor, a BC557 PNP Transistor, and a 47uF electrolytic capacitor.  You may ignore the voltage divider on the right.

I tested the schematic and it works, **but I am confused to see why Amir has chosen to use a capacitor.** I understand that reset has to be pulled to ground for a small amount of time; the capacitor somehow plays a part in that.

What I know so far:

1. The Reed switch is closed initially, which means that the mailbox lid is closed.  So a short circuit is formed and current does not flow into the circuit parallel to the reed switch.
2. When the mailbox opens, the reed switch opens.  This forces the current to flow into the 100K resistor and charge the capacitor.  After the capacitor fully charges, there will be a buildup of positive charge on the yellow wire. The build up of charge will be deposited to the base of the transistor.
3. I know that the base of the BC557 PNP Transistor requires a positive charge to activate the transistor.  And here lies the problem.  Can't the yellow wire simply bypass the capacitor and just go to the transistor?  **So what's the point of the capacitor?  It's going to short circuit!**
4. I know I should use NPN instead of PNP, but I feel like I should stick to the schematic since it works, somehow.  I mean, why is the GND even connected to the collector of the PNP transistor in the first place?

The goal of the circuit: Pull the Reset pin of the wifi module to Ground for a small amount of time.

Once again, here is what I'm asking for: **Can someone please explain how the circuit works with the capacitor to make that 'small amount of time' required to reset the module(Please include the movement of charges in your explanation)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference and to protect against future edits, here is the circuit being discussed:

[image]

Let's start with the steady state case with the switch closed for a long time.  Between R1 and the switch, C1 is discharged.  The base voltage of Q1 is Vdd, which means Q1 is not pulling down on the REST input.  For this circuit to make sense, we have to assume the REST input is internally pulled up.

When the switch opens, the immediate voltage on C1 stays 0.  This means that R1 and R2 form a voltage divider, producing 1/11 of Vcc, which is 340 mV.  That drives the base of Q1, which pulls its emitter down to about 600 mV above the base, or 940 mV.  If this circuit was competently designed (not clear that it was), then 940 mV is below the guaranteed logic low threshold of the REST input.

If the switch remains open, the current thru R1 and R2 charge up C1 with a time constant of about (R1 + R2)C1 = 5 seconds.  Eventually the capacitor will charge up enough so that the base of Q1 goes high, which makes the emitter go high, which no longer holds the REST input low.  If the switch is closed again, then the REST input is no longer pulled low immediately.

Comment: So should i use a PNP transistor or a NPN.